# How to compare floating points beyond just equality in perl

Tags: perl, floating-point

I am trying to compare two floats for greater than or equal to, and less than or equal to. The following code only allows me to measure equality (true or false). I need to measure >= and <=. I realize comparing floats is an issue in any language. I've tried to look up previous questions regarding this. All I could find was comparison for equality only. Any suggestions?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

my $a = 0.0;
my $b = 0.1;

if (abs($a - $b) < 0.0000001){
    print "True\n";
}
else{
    print "False\n";
}
```

Comment: If you have calculated two numbers with errors in them, you generally cannot determine which of the numbers would be greater if properly calculated.

Answer (score 4):

The scenario you are asking about is that you have two numbers, `$a` and `$b`, that are values you have computed while trying to calculate some exact mathematical values *a* and *b*. However, because any numerical arithmetic has errors in calculation, the values `$a` and `$b` contain errors that (probably) make them different from *a* and *b*. Then, given only `$a` and `$b`, you want to determine a relationship between *a* and *b*.

The rule here is garbage in, garbage out. When you have numbers containing errors, there are limited things you can do with them. You cannot determine the relationship perfectly.

How much can `$a` differ from *a*? How much can `$b` differ from *b*? There is no general answer to this question. It depends on what calculations you performed to get these values and what numbers were involved. The errors could range from zero to infinity or could give you non-numeric (NaN) results. Determining how much the error can be is hugely application-specific. No answer can be given without details about the computations you are performing.

After you have calculated how much error there can be, what do you do with it? The amount of error tells you how much “slop” there might be in `$a` and `$b`. If `$a` and `$b` differ by more than that amount of slop, terrific, you can be sure that *a* and *b* are definitely different. But, if `$a` and `$b` are within that slop distance, what can you say?

No determination is possible. You cannot know whether *a* and *b* are equal, whether *a* is greater, or whether *b* is greater. So what answer do you want in that case?

There is a myth, often repeated on Stack Overflow, that floating-point numbers ought to be compared for equality with a tolerance. The algorithm given with this myth almost always shows numbers reported as equal when the calculated values are within tolerance. But there is no reason that should be the right answer. Some applications will break if told two numbers are equal when they are not.

So the answer to be given when the correct answer cannot be determined depends on your application.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($a > $b - tolerance) ...    # $a >= $b
if ($a < $b + tolerance) ...    # $a <= $b
```

EDIT: It is safer to say

```
if ($a - $b > -tolerance) ...    # $a >= $b
if ($a - $b <  tolerance) ...    # $a <= $b
```

Comment: Is there some practical difference between `$a < $b + tolerance` and `$a - $b < tolerance`?

Comment: @mpapec: Yes. If `$b >> tolerance`, then maybe `$b + tolerance == $b` and the comparison fails when it should have passed. Updated my answer.

Comment: These tests do not correctly report whether the number that `$a` is intended to represent (if it had been calculated with exact mathematics) is greater than or equal to the number that `$b` is intended to represent, or vice-versa. It is impossible to reliably calculate a correct result from data containing numerical errors. If instead `tolerance` were calculated conclusively and the tests were changed to `$a - $b > tolerance` and `$a - $b < -tolerance`, then it could at least correctly give one of the answers “a is definitely greater than b”, “a is definitely less than b”, or “inconclusive”.